# Unable to Receive newAccessToken and newRefreshToken in Node.js JWT Authentication System

Tags: node.js, jwt

I've implemented a Node.js authentication system using JWT tokens and Redis for token storage. However, when attempting to refresh the access token (newAccessToken) and refresh token (newRefreshToken), I'm not receiving the expected tokens.

Here's my refresh function:

```
import Users from "../../models/Users.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import redis from "../../helpers/redis.js";

const generateAT = (payload) => {
    return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "30s",
    });
};

const generateRT = (payload) => {
    return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET);
};

export const register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password, email } = req.body;

        if (!username || !password || !email) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: `Missing required fields: ${!username ? "username" : ""} ${
                    !password ? "password" : ""
                } ${!email ? "email" : ""}`.trim(),
            });
        }

        const existingUser = await Users.findOne({
            $or: [{ username: username }, { email: email }],
        });

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists" });
        }

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const newUser = await Users.create({ username, password: hashed, email });

        const { password: userPassword, ...others } = newUser._doc;

        return res.status(200).json(others);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
};

export const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;

        if (!username || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: `Missing required fields: ${
                    !username ? "username or email" : ""
                } ${!password ? "password" : ""}`.trim(),
            });
        }

        const user = await Users.findOne({
            $or: [{ username: username }, { email: username }],
        });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Account not found" });
        }

        const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!passwordCompare)
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid password" });

        const { password: userPassword, ...others } = user._doc;

        const access_token = generateAT({ ...others });
        const refresh_token = generateRT({ ...others });

        await redis.set(`canopy_refresh_token:${user._id}`, refresh_token);

        res.cookie("refresh_token", refresh_token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            path: "/",
            sameSite: "strict",
        });

        return res.status(200).json({ ...others, access_token });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
};

export const refresh = async (req, res) => {
    const refresh_token = req.cookies.refresh_token;
    if (!refresh_token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "You're not authenticated" });
    }

    jwt.verify(
        refresh_token,
        process.env.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET,
        async (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            const redisCompare = await redis.get(`canopy_refresh_token:${user._id}`);

            if (redisCompare) {
                const newAccessToken = generateAT(user);
                const newRefreshToken = generateRT(user);

                await redis.set(`canopy_refresh_token:${user._id}`, newRefreshToken);
                await res.cookie("refresh_token", newRefreshToken, {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    secure: false,
                    path: "/",
                    sameSite: "strict",
                });

                return res.status(200).json({
                    access_token: newAccessToken,
                    refresh_token: newRefreshToken,
                });
            }

            if (!redisCompare) {
                return res.status(200).json({ message: "Token is not valid" });
            }
        },
    );
};
```

I've noticed that newAccessToken and newRefreshToken are not being received as expected. Could someone help me identify the issue in my code that might be causing this problem?

I want to receive a new access token and a new refresh token.